# Filling information from same and other tables in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

For my further work I need to create a lookup table where all the different IDs my data has (because of different sources) are noted.
It has to look like this:

Lookup_Table:

```
| Name | ID_source1 | ID_source2 | ID_source3 |
-----------------------------------------------
| John | EMP_992    | AKK81239K  | inv1000003 |
```

Note, that Name and ID_Source1 are coming from the same table. The other IDs are coming from different tables. They share the same name value, so e.g. source 2 looks like this:

Source2 Table:

```
| Name | ID        |
--------------------
| John | AKK81239K |
```

What is the SQL code to accomplish this? Im using Access and it doesnt seem to work with this code for source 2:

```
INSERT INTO Lookup_Table ([ID_Source2])
SELECT [Source2].[ID]
FROM Lookup_Table LEFT JOIN [Source2] 
ON [Lookup_Table].[Name] = [Source2].[Name]
```

It just adds the ID from Source2 in a new row:

```
| Name | ID_source1 | ID_source2 | ID_source3 |
-----------------------------------------------
| John | EMP_992    |            |            |
|      |            | AKK81239K  |            |
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT` query.

An `UPDATE` query updates existing records. An `INSERT` query inserts new records into a table.

```
UPDATE Lookup_Table 
INNER JOIN [Source2] ON [Lookup_Table].[Name] = [Source2].[Name]
SET [ID_Source2] = [Source2].[ID]
```